# two or more datatypes in PHPdoc @param

Tags: php, documentation, phpdoc

ok I do have this phpdoc above of my class method

```
/**
 * this a function that translates the text
 * @param string|boolean $lang if string the string given in the parameter will be the language code that will represent the language desired, if true, this will translate based on the website's current language, if false will not translate.
 */
```

now my problem is, is how I can define the datatype of the `$lang` that can accept both string and boolean ONLY.

In other documentations I saw `mixed` but its not reflecting correctly in my Eclipse IDE with PDT.

My question is what is the *standard way* on how i can display that a certain `@param` is possible to accept two or more kinds of datatype.

**NOTE**: the phpdoc i have given is an existing documentation of the application I am working at now. Well I'm assigned for documenting everything well.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You've done it right. The [PHPDoc reference](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.param.pkg.html) gives these two options for parameters that can be multiple data types (emphasis mine).

> The datatype should be a valid PHP type (int, string, bool, etc), a
>   class name for the type of object, or simply **"mixed"**. Further, you can
>   list multiple datatypes for a single parameter by delimiting them with
>   **the pipe (e.g. "@param int|string $p1").**

Comment: ahh.. well im just worried why the eclipse PDT is not displaying it well. ok thank you

Comment: @Mahan Is it displaying it differently than `@param integer` or `@param boolean`?

Comment: I think PDT still has some evolving to do with regard to being able to interpret everything that PHP docblocks have evolved to contain.  Perhaps a study to build a summary of how much docblock info each PDT version knows how to use is in order.